# Poison EncodeError unable to encode value. Verk package

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to build a simple mailer app with phoenix framework where I need to send non blocking emails. For that purpose I decided to use [Verk](https://github.com/edgurgel/verk) package.

The problem is when I pass a campaign object to Verk.enqueue, I get the following error.

```
Poison.EncodeError at POST /1/send
unable to encode value: {nil, "campaigns"}
```

-

```
  def send(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    campaign = Repo.get!(Campaign, id) |> Repo.preload(group: :users)


    Verk.enqueue(%Verk.Job{queue: :default,
                           class: "EmailWorker", args: [campaign], max_retry_count: 5})
  end
```

The following works but I have to wait a few seconds for it to finish.

```
Enum.each(campaign.group.users, fn(user) ->
  Email.campaign_email(campaign, user) |> Mailer.deliver_later()
end)
```

and if I add

```
  @derive {Poison.Encoder, only: [:name, :subject, :body]}
```

Here's what happens in terminal logs

```
[info] EmailWorker 3874693212000703845 start
[debug] Job failed reason: %KeyError{key: :group, term: %{"body" => "<h1>Hello</h1>\r\n\r\n<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>\r\n\r\n<p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>", "name" => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit", "subject" => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"}}
```

Comment: Try adding `:group` to the `only: []` list in the derive.

Comment: @Dogbert, If I just add `:group` to Campaign model it says `unable to encode value: {nil, "groups"}` And If I also add `only: [:user]` to Group model. It doesn't show any errors in browser. But in terminal it's still `[debug] Job failed reason: %KeyError{key: :group, term: %{"body" => "<h1>`

Comment: @Dogbert, I used campaign.name instead campaign["name"] in my worker. I guess this was my problem :/

Comment: I've never used Verk, but if it decodes to maps with string keys, then that sounds right since `.` only works for atom keys, and you'll need to use the bracket syntax.

Comment: Adding `:group` to Campaign and `:users` to Group encoders solved the problem.